# setBackgroundImage:forState: animation/transition?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uikit-transitions

I'm using [setBackgroundImage:forState:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#jumpTo_24) like so to tint the color of my background images for various states:

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage:genericImage forStates:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:buttonBackgroundPressed  
                   forStates:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Is there a means of animating/applying a fade-in/out duration transition directly to this method?

Comment: As far as I know there is not. But you can use `[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(fadeIn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownInside];` and put `[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]` into the fadeIn method.

Comment: @chris hrm.. doesn't seem to be working. I'll keep playing with it.

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me:

```
-(void) init{
  [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)touchUp:(id)sender
{
  UIButton* btn = sender;
  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    btn.alpha = 0.5;
  }];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I got it working with alpha too - but not yet with animating the background image. I'm suspecting I'm going to need to do it with the default (foreground) image :|